# Where MVC select routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I use MVC4, I look for event handler in which is made decision about usage route? When this event happend?

There is registration all routes (in `Application_Start()` event)

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Where is place in code, where is made decision which of route should be used when request appears?

Comment: are you talking about `ASP.NET MVC Framework`'s code responsible for analyzing routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in a class called `RouteConfig.cs` in **App_Start** folder.

[image]

Select the `RegisterRoutes` method and press **F12**, it will take you to the right place.

Answer (score 1):

It's configured in the method `RegisterRoutes` in the class `RouteConfig` which will be in the `App_Start` directory of the web project.